# unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:50299 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins, headless, headless-browser, selenium-chromedriver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:46050 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982129/unable-to-connect-to-chromedriver-http-127-0-0-146050-seleniumwebdrivere)

I installed jenkins on the amazon ec2 api and I am using jenkins to run my headless cucumber tests.

I downloaded the chromedriver, unzipped it and copy it to my path (/usr/bin) and changed the mode:

wget http://chromium.googlecode.com/files/chromedriver_linux32_18.0.1022.0.zip

unzip chromedriver_linux32_18.0.1022.0.zip

cp chromedriver /usr/bin

sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver

but when I run my tests(HEADLESS=true cucumber features), I get this error:

**unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:50299 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)**

which chromedriver:

/usr/bin/chromedriver

which google-chrome :

/usr/bin/google-chrome

I have the headless gem in my Gemfile and I also have the following code in env.rb:

if ENV['HEADLESS']

```
  require 'headless'

  headless = Headless.new

  headless.start

  at_exit do

    headless.destroy

  end

end
```

Did I miss anything?  Any ideas?