# R RSelenium/seleniumPipes Unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I try to connect with Selenium in R using the Chrome browser on Win10.

I installed Chrome 74.0.3729.61 and added the chrome.exe path to the Environment Variables.

```
devtools::install_github("johndharrison/seleniumPipes")
devtools::install_github("ropensci/Rselenium")

#start selenium
selServ <- selenium()
# check ports
selServ$log()$stderr 
# conect using port
sel <- remoteDr(browserName = "chrome", port = 4567)
```

gives me the following error message:

```
Called  newSession  - Try no:  1  of  3 

Called  newSession  - Try no:  2  of  3 

Called  newSession  - Try no:  3  of  3 
Error detected:
Response status code : 500 
Selenium Status code:  13 
Selenium Status summary:  UnknownError 
Selenium Status detail:  An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
Selenium message:  unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 40 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: ... , os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown 
Please check the response with errorResponse()
Please check the content returned with errorContent()
```

I found some guidance for Python ([Cannot find Chrome binary with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/cannot-find-chrome-binary-with-selenium-in-python-for-older-versions-of-google-c)) and c# ([Selenium WebDriver - Could not find Chrome binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507844/selenium-webdriver-could-not-find-chrome-binary)), however, I do not know how to implement it in R.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you need to download and run chomedriver.exe(if you are using Windows 10, as you mentioned) before to use selenium.
Could you try below solution?

Solution 1. on command window

> java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:/{yourPath}/selenium/chromedriver.exe" -jar "C:/{yourPath}/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" -port 4567

or

Solution 2. direct use R script

```r
rstudioapi::terminalExecute('java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:/{yourPath}/selenium/chromedriver.exe" -jar "C:/{yourPath}/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" -port 4567')
```

*Yes, both are same command exactly. You are able to use anyone you want.*

Comment: Thank you for your time. I downloaded the chromedriver.exe and the selenium-server-standalone and used your R script with my paths. However, I get the same error.